# Android altbeacon library for ibeacon is detecting device having uuid other than specified uuid

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

Android `altbeacon` library for `ibeacon` is detecting device having `uuid` other than specified `uuid` in

```
beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region(buuid, null, null, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the Region construction should not be the beacon proximity UUID.  It is a String identifier used to refer to the same region later.  The second parameter (null in your example) is the first beacon identifier (aka Proximity UUID) that you want to match.  By leaving it null, you make the region match all beacons.

Try:

```
 beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region(buuid, Identifier.parse(buuid), null, null));
```